# "Whose" but not in reference to humans

Tags: whose

I want to write "Hall thrusters are propulsion devices whose power spans from 0.1 to 20 kW."

I am not sure about "whose" part, because it feels like it's supposed to be used only when talking about humans (am I right?).

So is there any other word that could replace the "whose"? Or can it be used in this way and I am just overthinking it?

Comment: If you look up _whose_ in any decent dictionary (e.g., [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/whose)), you’ll see definitions and examples clearly include not only people, but also things; so yes, you’re over-thinking it. _Whose_ is fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I looked it up here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_(pronoun) and it said that it's mostly used when referring to humans, so I wasn't sure... But yeah, it looks like it's ok.

Comment: That’s because you looked up _who_, which is indeed limited to animate entities (mostly humans, sometimes animals) – but that’s a different word. _Whose_ is not only the possessive form of _who_, but also of _which_.